# PHP Secure Calculation

Tags: php, html, security

I have tried to find the answer to my question, but have no clue how to ask it (the way google would understand at least). I am new to webpages and for a work project I need to make a simple web interface that would ask users for parameters and then return some values. In the background there are some simple calculations, but they are a "secret". I need to know how something like this can be done. The input and return information can be completly unprotected, but the calculations and formulas should not be visible to anyone and need to be secured somehow.
I hope the question is specific enough.

Thank you in advance for anny help with the topic.

Comment: Since you have tagged php, if you are using php( or any server side language) then your formula code won't be available for users to see and copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the calculation part in your PHP, the back-end part is not visible.
But if you're affraid of specific attack, please tell us more.

Comment: I wrote some PHP code, but like i wrote before i have little to no understanding on how the server handles this, coul a skilled (like if someone hierd someone to retrive it for them) person retrive the PHP script that calculates in the background ?  i tought id use "<form action="calculate.php">" in HTML and then have a calculate.php script

Comment: It's ok to do that, the content of your form is sent to the php script and you can do your secret stuff properly.

If someone try to call the calculate.php he got nothing or error depending of your code, because your server interpret it before sent it, no PHP code is sent to the front.

Hope this can rassure you :)

Comment: In other hand, if you want to improve your security you have to change your code structure and how you build your site, often. Using framework and other technics. You have to judge and define what is necessary for your secret, because you increase also complexity for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, this answeared my question. I will get a few books and dive deeper but for a start this was great.

Comment: Glad to helped you :)